# Navigation won't stay inside header

Tags: css

When I resize the browser, the navigation goes into the grey area instead of staying in the black. Can someone help me understand why this doesn't work?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58t77g7q/2/

HTML

```
<body>
        <header>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1>Business Logo</h1>
                <nav class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">item 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">item 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">item 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div><!-- END OF NAV WRAPPER -->

        </header>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>


        <div class="wrapper">

            <div class="boxes">



            </div>

            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>

        </div> <!-- END OF BOXES WRAPPER -->
</body>
```

CSS

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}



/***********************************
    MAIN CONTENT
************************************/

body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; 
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #c5c5c5;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

.button {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 12px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #999;
    margin-top: 33px;
}

img {
    width: 187px;
    height: 187px;
}



/***********************************
    NAVIGATION
************************************/


header {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 4px solid yellow;
}

header h1 {
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: yellow;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.nav {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 13px;
}
/*
.nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
}*/

.nav li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color:  yellow;
}

.nav a {
    /*display: block;*/
    /*line-height: 2em;*/
    /*padding: 10px 10px;*/
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}



.boxes {
    /*position: relative;*/
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #999;
    width: 187px;
    height: 250px;
}





/***********************************
    FOOTER
************************************/

footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 25px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `min-width: 500px;` to your wrapper class like this:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 500px;
}
```